# array x array matrix in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

I'd like to convert from

```
{'key1' => (1..10) ,
 'key2' => (11..20) , 
'key3' => (21..30)}
```

to

```
[{'key1' => 1, 'key2' => 11, 'key3' => 21},
{'key1' => 1, 'key2' => 11, 'key3' => 22},...
 .
 .
{'key1' => 10, 'key2' => 20, 'key3' => 30}]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Freddie, I've edited my answer to address your comment and also added an alternative, which I think is an improvement.

Comment: What have you tried, they should ask you before they unleashed themselves to answer your otherwise trivial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is :

```
hsh = {'key1' => (1..10) ,'key2' => (11..20) , 'key3' => (21..30)}
keys = hsh.keys
hsh['key1'].to_a.product(hsh['key2'].to_a,hsh['key3'].to_a).map{|a|Hash[keys.zip(a)]}

# => [{'key1' => 1, 'key2' => 11, 'key3' => 21},
#   {'key1' => 1, 'key2' => 11, 'key3' => 22},...
#   .
#   .
#   {'key1' => 10, 'key2' => 20, 'key3' => 30}]
```

You could also write the above as below,when you have more number of keys:

```
hsh = {'key1' => (1..10) ,'key2' => (11..20) , 'key3' => (21..30)}
keys = hsh.keys
array = hsh.values_at(*keys[1..-1]).map(&:to_a)
hsh['key1'].to_a.product(*array).map{|a|Hash[keys.zip(a)]}
```

Comment: GREAT! Solution .. but can I calc it for any size of keys?

Comment: Interesting use of splat, Arup.  I borrowed it for my second answer.

Answer (score 2):

So many ways...  A kiss answer (edited to extend to any number of keys):

```
s = {'key1' => (1..10), 'key2' => (11..20), 'key3' => (21..30)}
r = []
s.each {|k,v| a = []; (v.to_a).each {|i| a << {k=>i}}; r << a}
result = r.shift
r.each {|e| result = result.product(e).map(&:flatten)}
result
```

Comment: GREAT! Solution! thank you so much. but can I calc it for any size of keys?

Comment: @Cary You can write I think `result[0].product(result[1]).product(result[2]).flatten(1)` as `result[0].product(*result[1..-1]).flatten`

Comment: Thanks, Arup.  You spotted my mistake.  I've edited the code to address SO's concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {
  'key1' => (1..10),
  'key2' => (11..20),
  'key3' => (21..30)
}

h.map { |k,v| [k].product(v.to_a) }.transpose.map { |e| Hash[e] }
#=> [{"key1"=>1, "key2"=>11, "key3"=>21},
#    {"key1"=>2, "key2"=>12, "key3"=>22},
#    {"key1"=>3, "key2"=>13, "key3"=>23},
#    {"key1"=>4, "key2"=>14, "key3"=>24},
#    {"key1"=>5, "key2"=>15, "key3"=>25},
#    {"key1"=>6, "key2"=>16, "key3"=>26},
#    {"key1"=>7, "key2"=>17, "key3"=>27},
#    {"key1"=>8, "key2"=>18, "key3"=>28},
#    {"key1"=>9, "key2"=>19, "key3"=>29},
#    {"key1"=>10, "key2"=>20, "key3"=>30}]
```

Comment: Interesting use of `transpose`, Stefan.  I've tucked that into my grey cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {'key1' => (1..10) ,
'key2' => (11..20) , 
'key3' => (21..30)}

arrays = h.values.map(&:to_a).transpose
p arrays.map{|ar| Hash[h.keys.zip(ar)] }
#=> [{"key1"=>1, "key2"=>11, "key3"=>21}, {"key1"=>2, "key2"=>12, "key3"=>22},...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {'key1' => (1..10), 'key2' => (11..20), 'key3' => (21..30)}
```

Edit 1: made some changes, principally the use of `inject({})`:

```
f,*r = h.map {|k,v| [k].product(v.to_a)}
f.zip(*r).map {|e| e.inject({}) {|h,a| h[a.first] = a.last; h}}
```

Edit 2: After seeing the use of Hash[] in @Phrogz's answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100525/all-combinations-for-hash-of-arrays/19105573#19105573):

```
f,*r = h.map {|k,v| [k].product(v.to_a)}
f.zip(*r).map {|e| Hash[*e.flatten]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazier way of doing the same:

```
h = {
  'key1' => (1..10),
  'key2' => (11..20),
  'key3' => (21..30)
}

result = ( 0...h.values.map( &:to_a ).map( &:size ).max ).map do |i|
  Hash.new { |hsh, k| hsh[k] = h[k].to_a[i] }
end

result[1]['key3'] #=> 22
```