# All combinations for hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, cartesian-product

**Summary**
Given a Hash where some of the values are arrays, how can I get an array of hashes for all possible combinations?

**Test Case**

```
options = { a:[1,2], b:[3,4], c:5 }
p options.self_product
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>5}]
```

*When the value for a particular key is not an array, it should simply be included as-is in each resulting hash, the same as if it were wrapped in an array.*

**Motivation**
I need to generate test data given a variety of values for different options. While I can use `[1,2].product([3,4],[5])` to get the Cartesian Product of all possible values, I'd rather use hashes to be able to label both my input and output so that the code is more self-explanatory than just using array indices.

Comment: Can you explain how it is not a duplicate of the linked question? Do you mean when a value is not an array?

Comment: @sawa No, for the linked question there would only be two results: `[{a:1,b:3},{a:2,b:4}]`. The linked question is about paired values, not products.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a little pre-processing to keep the result general:

```
options = { a:[1,2], b:[3,4], c:5 }
options.each_key {|k| options[k] = [options[k]] unless options[k].is_a? Array}  
=> {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 4], :c=>[5]}
```

I edited to make a few refinements, principally the use of `inject({})`:

```
class Hash
  def self_product
    f, *r = map {|k,v| [k].product(v).map {|e| Hash[*e]}}
    f.product(*r).map {|a| a.inject({}) {|h,e| e.each {|k,v| h[k]=v}; h}}
  end
end
```

...though I prefer @Phrogz's '2nd attempt', which, with pre-processing `5=>[5]`, would be:

```
class Hash
  def self_product
    f, *r = map {|k,v| [k].product(v)}
    f.product(*r).map {|a| Hash[*a.flatten]}
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the elegant first/rest solution. Note that this requires every value to be an array. You can 'destructure' your `p` array like so: `a.each{ |(a,b)| h[a]=b }` for a roughly 10% speed improvement.

Comment: Thank you, @Phrogz.  I saw your comment after making a few changes. I would welcome any further suggstions you may wish to offer.

Answer (score 1):

First attempt:

```
class Hash
  #=> Given a hash of arrays get an array of hashes
  #=> For example, `{ a:[1,2], b:[3,4], c:5 }.self_product` yields
  #=> [ {a:1,b:3,c:5}, {a:1,b:4,c:5}, {a:2,b:3,c:5}, {a:2,b:4,c:5} ]
  def self_product
    # Convert array values into single key/value hashes
    all = map{|k,v| [k].product(v.is_a?(Array) ? v : [v]).map{|k,v| {k=>v} }}
    #=> [[{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}], [{:b=>3}, {:b=>4}], [{:c=>5}]]

    # Create the product of all mini hashes, and merge them into a single hash
    all.first.product(*all[1..-1]).map{ |a| a.inject(&:merge) }
  end
end

p({ a:[1,2], b:[3,4], c:5 }.self_product)
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>5}, 
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>5}]
```

Second attempt, inspired by @Cary's answer:

```
class Hash
  def self_product
    first, *rest = map{ |k,v| [k].product(v.is_a?(Array) ? v : [v]) }
    first.product(*rest).map{ |x| Hash[x] }
  end
end
```

In addition to being more elegant, the second answer is also about 4.5x faster than the first when creating a large result (262k hashes with 6 keys each):

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  n = *1..8
  h = { a:n, b:n, c:n, d:n, e:n, f:n }
  %w[phrogz1 phrogz2].each{ |n| x.report(n){ h.send(n) } }
end
#=>              user     system      total        real
#=> phrogz1  4.450000   0.050000   4.500000 (  4.502511)
#=> phrogz2  0.940000   0.050000   0.990000 (  0.980424)
```

Comment: You can replace `v.is_a?(Array) ? v : [v]` with `Array(v)`

Comment: @tihom No, you cannot. Given `v = {}`, `v.is_a?(Array) ? v : [v]` is `[{}]`, and `Array(v)` is `[]`.

Comment: @sawa ...thanks...did not consider that possibility

Comment: +1 I somehow wasn't aware of `Hash[]` as you use it in your "2nd attempt".  That's quite neat (e.g., I can see use of `Hash[arr.flatten]`).  Thanks!